# R Studio Shiny zoom subapplication

Tags: r, shiny, zooming, subapplication

I have a Shiny "Sub"App called "Bayes Formel" in my Main App

[Main App with Sub App "BayesFormel"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLKBv.png)

```
uimain <- shinyUI( 

BayesFormel <- shiny::shinyAppFile( 
appFile= 'subdir/BayesFormel.R', options=list( width="100%", height=550))
)
servermain <- function(input, output, session) {
}
shinyApp(ui = uimain, server = servermain)
```

I'm looking for a way to zoom in and zoom out the subapp
NOT changing width and height (otherwise I get scrollbars what I don't want)

I've tried 
tags$style("body {  transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);   }") but then it leave white space around, from the "original" width and height

Any ideas how to solve that problem?
Thanks!!!